# Maths + Graphic Design - Did somebody try that?

Tags: typography, information-graphics, typesetting, data-visualisation, mathematics

Hello and wish you a nice day to all. I'm working on project of visualizating math formulas into such form that it would be easily comprehensible and readable, simply beautiful to look at. I've been wondering if there ever have been artists who worked on the same topic. I've been searching for long to find any resource connected to this topic, but I couldn't find even a slight indication of someone diving into this. If you allow me I would like to ask you all this question;

Are there any artists who have been working on projects related to typography, graphic design or visualization of mathematical notations/concepts? (I mostly mean from artistic side of view.)

Thank you!

Comment: What comes to my mind are these kinds of objects: http://9gag.com/gag/aNexNKr. Art? Maybe not, but none the less visualized and tangible math :)

Comment: I would say it depends on each individual formula. Some formulas lead to easy visualisations. Others really do not. So each formula is a separate art problem. Graphics design is not art, atleast not really, by the way.

Comment: Yes, that's true and I agree with that point. Perhaps, I should have said that what I mean is more related to typography of math notation than some tangible specific art projects. To be more specific, I'm looking for someone who has been thinking about turning something like this http://www.math10.com/en/university-math/integrals/imgFig17.gif into something more visually appealing while still remaining 2D.

Comment: so your looking into typesetting math? In that case your tags are misleading.

Comment: Typesetting is one part of what I'm looking for. I'm looking for any projects, resources, people who has been working on graphical design of mathematical formulas, equations, scientific papers etc. I apologize if my tags are misleading.

Comment: Take a look at something like _Processing_ maybe - see this [portfolio](http://www.openprocessing.org/user/5827) for instance, or a sketch such as [this](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/31295). Also a toolkit like [openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/tutorials/) may provide facilities for showcasing such ideas...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher#Mathematically-inspired_work

Answer (score 3):

Type designer Hermann Zapf created a typeface specifically for this purpose: AMS Euler. I guess it is both easily comprehensible and readable, if it is also beautiful to look at, you will have to decide for yourself.

Read more about it on the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMS_Euler